# Get key value from the list of JSON in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js

I am receiving the JSON object as a list of objects:

```
result=[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

I am trying to retrieve the values from this list in Node.js. I used `JSON.stringify(result)` but failed. I have been trying to iterate the list using `for(var key in result)` with no luck, as it prints each item as a key.

Is anyone facing a similar issue or has been through this? Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 25):

If your result is a string then:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log(obj[keys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! if I received data as json then I do not need to generate an associative array. this answer was so appropriate.

also you can write:


var obj = JSON.parse(result);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.forEach(function (value,i) {
          console.log(obj[value]);
      }

Answer (score 5):

Lookslike you are pointing to wrong object.
Either do like

```js
var result = [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}];
for(var key in result[0]){ alert(key);}
```

or

```js
var keys = Object.keys([{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}][0]);
alert(keys);
```

Answer (score 5):

Okay, assuming that `result` here is a string, the first thing you need to do is to convert (deserialize) it to a JavaScript object. A great way of doing this would be:

```
array = JSON.parse(result)
```

Next you loop through each item in the array, and for each item, you can loop through the keys like so:

```
for(var idx in array) {
  var item = array[idx];
  for(var key in item) {
    var value = item[key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't this just be:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(result);
let arrValues = Object.values(obj);
```

which would give you an array of just the values to iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

A little different approach:

```
let result=[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
for(let i of result){
    console.log("i is: ",i)
    console.log("key is: ",Object.keys(i));
    console.log("value is: ",Object.keys(i).map(key => i[key])) // Object.values can be used as well in newer versions.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this code:**

```
For result=[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

Below will print the values for Individual Keys:

```
console.log(result[0].key1)

console.log(result[0].key2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for JsonObject (not JsonArray per se).  `p` is your jsonobject the key pairs are `key` and `p[key]`

```
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain it a little bit to get a better understanding.